# Get the file extension

Tags: php

I'm exploding on "." to get file format and name:

```
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
```

The problem is that some files have names with dots.

How do I explote on the LAST "." so that I get `$name=pic.n2` and `$ext=jpg` from: `pic.n2.jpg`?

Comment: Are you working with a local file, or random text?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [pathinfo](http://us.php.net/pathinfo):

```
$pi = pathinfo($name);
$txt = $pi['filename'];
$ext = $pi['extension'];
```

Comment: Awesome, much more elegant than my solution

Answer (score 12):

```
$name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext  = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

http://www.php.net/pathinfo

Answer (score 6):

use this

```
$array = explode(".", $name);
end($array);         // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$filetype = current($array);
```

thanks

Comment: There's also the `current` function instead of your `key` roundabout way of getting the *current element*.

Comment: `$filetype = end($array);` also works. No need for the last additional line.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's pathinfo() function.

See more information here http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$file_part = pathinfo('123.test.php');
```

Example:

```
echo $file_part['extension'];
echo $file_part['filename'];
```

Output:

php
123.test

Answer (score 1):

Use Pathinfo or mime_content_type to get file type information

```
$filetype = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$path = 'http://www.mytest.com/public/images/portfolio/i-vis/abc.y1.jpg';
echo $path."<br/>";
$name = basename($path);
$dir = dirname($path); 
echo $name."<br/>";
echo $dir."<br/>";
$pi = pathinfo($path);
$txt = $pi['filename']."_trans";
$ext = $pi['extension'];
echo $dir."/".$txt.".".$ext;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own function as

> function getExtension($str) {
>
> $i = strrpos($str,".");
>
> if (!$i) { return ""; }
>
> $l = strlen($str) - $i;
>
> $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
>
> return $ext;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
<?php
$file = 'a.cool.picture.jpg';

$ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.')+1, strlen($file)-strrpos($file, '.'));
$name = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));
echo $name.'.'.$ext;
?>
```

The key functions are strrpos() which finds the last occurrence of a character (a "." in this case) and substr() which returns a sub string. You find the last "." in the file, and sub string it. Hope that helps.

Comment: I like the explode function as well, though getting the file name requires looping or imploding, whereas this is more to the point. (Messy code as it is, granted.)

Comment: You don't have to supply the 3rd argument to `substr`, `substr($file, strrpos($file, '.')+1)` alone is fine for finding the extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use one of the solutions above, but there is also a solution using the explode function:

```
$filename = "some.file.name.ext";
list($ext, $name) = explode(".", strrev($filename), 2);
$name = strrev($name);
$ext = strrev($ext);
```

What this solution does is the following:
1. reverse string, so it will look like: txe.eman.elif.emos
2. explode it, you will get something like: $ext = "txe", $name = "eman.elif.emos"
3. reverse each of the variables to get the correct results